# What version of Visual studio 11 is bundled with Windows 8 Developer Preview?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

is the version of Visual studio 11 bundled with Windows 8 Developer preview the same as the version available as standalone download from Microsoft site ?

cause i have noticed the one bundled with windows 8 only have metro-style/Grid Projects..

Comment: The bundled version requires a DVD writer that can write dual-layered DVD disks.  Ignoring that probably isn't a good idea.  Not sure, don't have one, didn't try.  Does anybody outside Redmond have one?

Comment: Hans i managed to installed it using 8GB USB Flash Memory..

Comment: You can also try it with VMware or HyperV

Comment: See: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/toolsforwinapps/thread/12057f17-2f6c-422e-836e-47bcb1656a5d

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The version included with the [Windows 8 Developer Preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229516) is the Express Edition.  The version available for [download](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27538) is different - I am guessing from the file names and description that it is the VS Ultimate edition.

Here's an [MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2011/09/14/announcing-visual-studio-11-developer-preview.aspx) announcing the VS 11 Developer Preview, with additional information links.

Comment: Yes the standalone version is the ultimate version, i just downloaded it and installed it on Windows 7